# Обновить записи в таблице?

Tags: mysql

Есть задача. Нужно вбить в поле процент, и на этот процент уменьшить увеличить поле price в выбранной категории, а значение которое было в поле price записать в old_price.

```
UPDATE tm_product 
SET price = price  + (price/100)*'$discount' 
WHERE id_category='$category' 
  AND id_subcategory='$subcategory'
```

вот так я обновляю запись в таблице, а как мне обновить поле old_price == старое значение price. Т.Е. сделать запрос до этого? Какой запрос?

Comment: `old_price=price, price = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как мне обновить поле old_price == старое значение price. Т.Е. сделать запрос до этого?

В секции SET запроса UPDATE можно выполнить несколько присвоений, изменяя значения одного и того же и/или разных полей, разделяя присвоения запятыми, при этом присвоения выполняются строго в порядке их следования.

Т.е. сначала надо сохранить старое значение, а потом посчитать и изменить текущее:

```
UPDATE tm_product 
SET old_price = price,
    price = price  + (price/100)*'$discount'
WHERE id_category='$category' 
  AND id_subcategory='$subcategory'ж
```